# Android Emulator is running in vs code but not in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When I choose particular emulator in android studio from the drop down option, It starts the emulator but still shows

But In vs code it works fine..

Comment: you should give a try with low end device and little lower api like 28 or 29

Comment: emulator is running even for android native apps.. but while developing flutter apps , its showing <no device selected>

Comment: I know bro but could you please try what I just said.. choose low end screen Android phone and API 28 or lower

Comment: what is low end screen phone ??

Comment: Choose Small screen phone in emulator

Comment: ok bro tnx......

Comment: I would say best is to use real device.